# FeathersJS: Custom Method in a Generic Service

Tags: feathersjs

Is there any way to expose custom methods (aside from the defaults: [get, find, update, patch, remove]) in a generic service? I have already tried creating one, but it seems to be not accessible when I tried to use it.

Comment: Feathers does not allow to do that for several good reasons. See https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/readme.html#caveats for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Custom service for the each custom method works well. Thank you so much for the good documentation.

Comment: This page https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/readme.html#caveats is not online anymore. Is there a replacement you know of, @Daff? I am on the same situation and would like to understand how this works and what are my other possibilities.

Comment: https://docs.feathersjs.com/help/faq.html#how-do-i-create-custom-methods